# NativeMessaging c# Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, chrome-extension, native

Не до конца понимаю как мне связать приложение C# с расширением Chrome.

Хелп.

По сути мне нужно чтобы расширение вызывало мое C# приложение, которое цепляет dll-ки уже настроенные

Comment: Разобрался, вопрос теперь в другом, не могу отправить сообщение уже в само приложение, от него сообщения получаю без проблем, а отправить не могу, есть ли пример кода?

Comment: Возможно вот этот пример [native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:native) вам поможет.